# How to login to a website using python and upload a file to s3?

Tags: python, html, authentication, amazon-s3, python-requests

I have a script that uploads a file from a public URL to S3 which is working fine. i have a need to use this script to upload some files which are not Public, i need to log in to the site to get the file. i need help implementing this in my script; where the script would log in to the site and get the file. site i am trying to login to https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/login

Here is my Script

```
import threading
import requests
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig

def multi_part_upload_with_s3():
    config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=1024 * 25, max_concurrency=30,
                            multipart_chunksize=1024 * 25, use_threads=True)
    url = "www.example-url.com"
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    session = boto3.Session()
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    key = 'examplePath/file'
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    bucket.upload_fileobj(r.raw, key, Config=config, Callback=None)
```

Here is the html from the site i need to log in to

```
<form class="new_spree_user" id="new_spree_user" action="/login" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="xjxGqf8OYqJd6Ynt1GcK1Ms0XM6YcPz3kS69TFKCCRQwOgwh1kEMlpJSTKAoblXLtLpSLCIiwPWT+LLab0Altw==">
  <div id="password-credentials">
    <p>
      <label for="spree_user_email">E-mail</label><br>
      <input class="title" tabindex="1" type="text" name="spree_user[login]" id="spree_user_login">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="spree_user_password">Password</label><br>
      <input class="title" tabindex="2" type="password" name="spree_user[password]" id="spree_user_password">
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>
      <input name="spree_user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="spree_user[remember_me]" id="spree_user_remember_me">
      <label for="spree_user_remember_me">Remember me</label>
  </p>

  <p><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login" class="button primary" tabindex="3" id="submit_form" data-disable-with="Login"></p>
</form>
    or
    <a href="/signup">Create a new account</a> |
    <a href="/password/recover">Forgot password?</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried selenium?

Comment: i can log in to the site using webdriver.Chrome() `driver.get('https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/login')
driver.find_element_by_id('spree_user_login').send_keys('username')
driver.find_element_by_id('spree_user_password').send_keys('password)
driver.find_element_by_id('submit_form').click()` but now what?

Comment: You need to mimic all clicks (like you did to login) to upload a file.